# Find the minimum value of this complex expression

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

**Z is a complex number ; $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Find the minimum value of $$|Z-2(1+i)|+|Z+1-5i|+|Z-6+2i|$$**

I am interested in a geometric method to solve this problem. I tried to use triangle inequality but couldn't make it.

Comment: Using Argand's plane representation, It seems that you a re searching a point $Z$ such that the sum of the distances from three given pints is minimum. Geometrically this is the so called Fermat's point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point

Answer (score 1):

$|z-a|$ represents the distance of $z$ from $a$

hence,

$|z-2(1+i)|$ represents the distance of $z$ from $2(1+i)$ it is true for all others too

so, if you see the points $(2,2);(-1,5);(6,-2)$ {it's my way to represent complex no. on the argand plane (real part, imaginary part)}

so these points are collinear hence the minimum distance is possible only when z lies on the line joining these points specifically $(2,2)$  (think why?) so the distance is just the distance between $(-1,5)$ and $(6,-2)$ which is $7\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 0):

A harder way of solving, instead of the geometrical way:

When $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

1. $$\text{Z}_1=\left|\text{z}-2\left(1+i\right)\right|=\sqrt{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]-2\right)^2+\left(\Im\left[\text{z}\right]-2\right)^2}$$
2. $$\text{Z}_2=\left|\text{z}+1-5i\right|=\sqrt{\left(1+\Re\left[\text{z}\right]\right)^2+\left(\Im\left[\text{z}\right]-5\right)^2}$$
3. $$\text{Z}_3=\left|\text{z}-6+2i\right|=\sqrt{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]-6\right)^2+\left(2+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]\right)^2}$$

So, we get:

$$\text{Z}\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right],\Im\left[\text{z}\right]\right)=\text{Z}_1+\text{Z}_2+\text{Z}_3$$

In order to find the minimum:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial\space\text{Z}\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right],\Im\left[\text{z}\right]\right)}{\partial\Re\left[\text{z}\right]}=0\\
\\
\frac{\partial\space\text{Z}\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right],\Im\left[\text{z}\right]\right)}{\partial\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}=0
\end{cases}
$$